# How can I hide or remove a menu item?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, menu-items

I have the following snippet of code that creates a list of navigation items (a menu):

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li><%= link_to "Log in", login_path %></li>
  <li><%= link_to "Help", help_path %></li>
  <% if logged_in? %>
  <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
</ul>
```

When I am not logged in, the menu shows as:

> `Log in` `Help`

When I do log in, it shows as

> `Log in` `Help` `Home`

After logging in, I'd like to:

1. hide or remove the `log in` menu item and
2. rearrange the remainder menu items so that `Home` is first and `Help` is next.

Comment: Maybe I'm unclear what you're asking, but why is hiding the "Log in" link more complicated than hiding the "Home" link, which you're already doing? If the "Home" link is only when you're logged in, and you want it shown before the "Help" link when you're logged in, just move it before the "Help" link. (I'm assuming the missing `end` tag is just a copy-pasta-to-SO error)

Comment: I am actually not hiding the "Home" link. There is one partial View _header.html.erb, which contains the code. The IF statement controls what gets displayed based on log in status. However, once logged in the "Log in" link continues to show (and it shouldn't because the user has already logged in). If I am able to remove "Home" and "Help", I should be able to rearrange them so the second part is not so hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to arrange them properly and use the condition properly

```
<ul class="nav">
  <% if logged_in? %>
    <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
  <% else %>
    <li><%= link_to "Log in", login_path %></li>
  <% end %>
  <li><%= link_to "Help", help_path %></li>
</ul>
```

**Explanation:**

The first if-else checks for a logged in user and will return the `<li>` **Home** if logged in or **Log in**  If not logged in

The last `<li>` will always be displayed no matter user is logged in or not

Answer (score 1):

Above answers are correct but its old method, you can do it without if else condition. rails provide built in [link_to_unless](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to_unless) helper .
please check below code.
you can arrange menus as per your requirement.

**Not Tested**

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li><%= link_to_unless(logged_in?, 'Log in', login_path){} %></li>
  <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
  <li><%= link_to "Help", help_path %></li>
</ul>
```

Let me know if its not work

Comment: `link_to_unless` always returns text. Just creates the link conditionally.

Comment: So, in this case if the user is logged in you will still see plain text `Log in` without the link

Comment: @DeepakMahakale i added a blank block, so it won't so any link or text.

Comment: you can test it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do an if else statement to help you here.

```
<ul class="nav">
  <% if logged_in? %>
    <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
  <% else %>
    <li><%= link_to "Log in", login_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Help", help_path %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your first two are set to show whether a user is logged in or not, so they show no matter what.